# Read SonarQube properties of gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm using Gradle 2.14. 
I'd like to read the report-task.txt generated by the SonarQube Gradle plugin. For this purpose I need to get the location of this file which is stored in

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        sonar.working.directory "..."
    }
}
```

I want to access this property from outside the sonarqube plugin, i.e. I'm writing a gradle task that runs after the sonar task. This tasks needs to process the report-task.txt located in sonar.working.directory.

Is is possible to access the properties of a gradle plugin?

Comment: How about you use an `ext` variable, that you then use in the sonarqube extension as well as in your other task?

Comment: thought about that, too. but i'd like to use the defaults from sonarqube. If accessing those properties is not possible I stick with that solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The task `sonarqube` exposes all of the defined properties:

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.0.1"
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.working.directory", "..."
    }
}

task printSonarqubeProperty {
    doLast {
        println "${project.tasks['sonarqube'].properties['sonar.working.directory']}"
    }
}
```